# Counting how many times a point goes through a loop and write the count to a text

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcpy

I have a several feature classes that go through a loop to calculate points.  I want to add up how many go through it each time so I can archive that number.  I'm using ArcGIS 10.1.   Lets say I have 100 shapefiles with anywhere between 1 - 50 points per shapefile. I want to run a count on the total number of points in those 100 shapefiles. Right now it's printing out the total number of points in each shapefile loop. Is there a way to add the 'count' up to create a total?

```
SMON = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("SectMon_PLSS_*")
for fc in SMON:
        filename =  "'" + arcpy.env.workspace + os.sep + fc + "'"
        arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
        arcpy.AddField_management(fc, 'shpname','text')
        arcpy.AddField_management(fc, 'GIS_ID_PAM','text')
        arcpy.AddField_management(fc, 'LATDMS','text')
        arcpy.AddField_management(fc, 'LONGDMS','text')
        arcpy.AddField_management(fc, 'DESC_','text')
        arcpy.AddField_management(fc, 'StatePlane','text')
        arcpy.AddField_management(fc, 'State','text')
        for fc in SMON:
            result = arcpy.GetCount_management(fc)
            count = int(result.getOutput(0))
            x.append(count)
            c = sum(x for x in x)
            print "The cumulative sum for this iteration is %s" %c
```

This is what the printouts are giving me:

> > > ```
> > >  P:\Scripts\SystemData\TestData\TO PAM\140306_BCR_PNTS102034-102035&103003-103005 (1).shp
> > >  This is located in Colorado North
> > >  This is located in Colorado North
> > >  This is located in Colorado North
> > >  This is located in Colorado North
> > >  This is located in Colorado North
> > >  Fields Calculated
> > >  The cumulative sum for this iteration is 5
> > >  #############COLORADO NORTH FINISHED################
> > >  P:\Scripts\SystemData\TestData\5pm\140226_BCR_PNTS100463-100465.shp
> > >  This is located in North Dakota North
> > >  This is located in North Dakota North
> > >  This is located in North Dakota North
> > >  Fields Calculated
> > >  The cumulative sum for this iteration is 3
> > >  P:\Scripts\SystemData\TestData\5pm\140311_BCR_PNT100466.shp
> > >  This is located in North Dakota North
> > >  Fields Calculated
> > >  The cumulative sum for this iteration is 1
> > >  P:\Scripts\SystemData\TestData\5pm\140312_BCR_PNTS100467-100469.shp
> > >  This is located in North Dakota North
> > >  This is located in North Dakota North
> > >  This is located in North Dakota North
> > >  Fields Calculated
> > >  The cumulative sum for this iteration is 3
> > >  #############NORTH DAKOTA FINISHED################
> > > ```

I want to be able write to a log file each time it goes through a loop.  I'm trying this, but it's giving me an error.

```
            txtFile = open(count,"a")
            txtFile.write("This is the total amount " + str(c))
```

It's telling me "coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found"

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get a count of all of the features (e.g. rows) in your point feature class for each iteration, you can use [Get Count (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//0017000000n7000000).  Then use a generator to count your points on a cumulative basis.

Here would be one way to count your *cumulative* points for each iteration:

```
SMON = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("SectMon_PLSS_*")

x = []
for fc in SMON:
    result = arcpy.GetCount_management(Control)
    count = int(result.getOutput(0))
    x.append(count)
    c = sum(x for x in x)
    print "The cumulative sum for this iteration is %s" %c
```

Comment: Where would this go?  Below the code?

Comment: OK, I think I got to the jist of your question.  However, your script does not make sense for a few reasons: 1) your `for` loop is incorrectly indented and 2) you are not using "ControlPoints" at all in the script.

Comment: Yeah, I just gave a snippet of the code.  Control points belong in a different loop.  The script is working and adding each point in each feature class.  How do I keep a running total of these?

Comment: Could you please describe what "adding each point in each feature class" means?  Does Get Count work for your script?  If not, why not?

Comment: Aaron, I've updated the code so it makes more sense.  I get it to print out the points in each feature class it loops through.  Can I get it to add those up each time it loops through to get a running total?

Comment: So lets say I have 100 shapefiles with anywhere between 1 - 50 points per shapefile.  I want to run a count on the total number of points in those 100 shapefiles.  Right now it's printing out the total number of points in each shapefile loop.  Is there a way to add the 'count' up to create a total?

Comment: OK, now I understand.  See updated post.

Comment: That's still only counting to total for the loop.  I changed (Control) to (fc) for it to run correctly.  I've updated what my code is printing out in the interpreter. Thanks for the help!

Comment: The current script I posted works...I just checked it.

Comment: Maybe I'm confused on where to put it?  It does work, but only each shapefile.  It's not adding the the count from each of the shapefiles up.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13584/discussion-between-aaron-and-joebob)